# Reset Fields on AMP Form Submission

Tags: forms, amp-html

I want to reset all the form fields on successful AMP form submission as I am allowing user for multiple data entry.

Manually I can do it by managing states of each field through `amp-bind` but I want to reset fields in one go. Is there any function like `form.reset` present which I can call on form submit success event?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`clear` action](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/#form_1) to reset all fields in a form:

```
<form id=myForm>
  <input>
</form>
<button on="tap:myForm.clear">Clear inputs</button>
```

Comment: When we call the `clear` method, the message in the `submit-success` block is also cleared. How to clear clear inputs without clearing the `submit-success`block? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `submit-success`.

```html
<form id=myForm on=submit-success: myForm.clear>
  <input name=name value= />
<button>Submit form</button>
</form>
```